# scrape html tag with regex. Very confused

Tags: php, regex, curl

4 hours attempting to learn regex and I am always getting an error. I want get `action` value for cURL.

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="M_Username_Password.aspx?__ufps=802858&amp;84E09046BECF819E=6C1143C04AF5072F1DF5B1C51C90DACB">
```

Take this part from the form tag:

```
M_Username_Password.aspx?__ufps=802858&amp;84E09046BECF819E=6C1143C04AF5072F1DF5B1C51C90DACB
```

And use it with cURL.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://website.com/$linkaction");
```

`$linkaction` is an example.

Answer (score 0):

[Regular expression](http://regex101.com/r/hC6bW9):

```
<form.*?action="([^"]*)".*?>
```

Combined with [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$html = '<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="M_Username_Password.aspx?__ufps=802858&amp;84E09046BECF819E=6C1143C04AF5072F1DF5B1C51C90DACB">'; // from cURL
preg_match_all('/<form.*?action="([^"]*)".*?>/i', $html, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]); // An array of form actions
// array(1) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(92) "M_Username_Password.aspx?__ufps=802858&84E09046BECF819E=6C1143C04AF5072F1DF5B1C51C90DACB"
// }
```

But in the end, [don't rely on regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Try a DOM parser like [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).